# Кэш для AJAX Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

у меня есть событие hover, которое вызывает ajax с запросом на сервер. Так вот как применить кэширование - чтобы при следующих hover информация бралась уже из кэша без запроса

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$.data('#some_element','cached_content')){
  $.ajax({
    'url': 'my_url/',
    'success':function(data){
      $.data('#some_element','cached_content',data);
      fill_element();//некий метод, заполняющий некий элемент теми самыми данными.
    } 
  });
}else{
   fill_element();
}
```

например, так. Можно свою переменную завести.
Примечание: свойство "cache" у аякса лишь советует браузеру прокэшировать ответ и только для метода GET.

Comment: я бы fill_element ещё сделал через stTimeout, чтобы асинхронность соблюсти.